# Ubuntu Display Error Chrome Ubuntu 14.04.01

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, display, google

I have a Problem. My Display making a Blackscreen if i opening the Chrome Webstore or something from Google. I become a Blackscreen and dont can become it on. Help Me. (Oh i have a Problem with Ubuntu 14.04.01 not with 14.10, 14.04 or 13.10 and 13.04(.1.2.3.4))
If any can help me, Thanks? :D

Comment: So what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by reinstalling it?

Note :  There is also a browser called **Chromium** which servers as a base for Google Chrome.On ubuntu, I suggest you to use Chromium.